# Add attributes to element in template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

**Perl code**

Passing menu items as perl array containing link hashes

```
my $bet_details_menu_items = [ 
    {   
        link        => 'link 1',
        text         => 'First',
        is_internal  => 1
    },  
    {   
        link        => 'link 2'
        text        => 'Second',
        params      => { param_name1 => param_value1, param_name2 => param_value2 },
    }                                                       
];
```

**Template Toolkit Code**

Accessing the links using template toolkit for each

```
<ul>
    [% FOREACH item IN menu_items %]
    <li>
        [% IF item.is_internal%]
        <a href="#[% item.link %]">[% item.text %]</a>
        [% ELSE %]
        <a href="[% item.link %]">[% item.text %]</a>
        [% END %]
    </li>
    [% END %]
</ul>
```

**What I have tried**

I tried assigning all params to a variable with key and value both and then assigning it to the corresponding link

```
[% all_params = '' %]
[% FOREACH param IN params.keys %]
[% $all_params = $all_params _  param  _ '=' _ params.$param %]
[% END %] 
[% IF item.is_internal %]
<a href="#[% item.link %]" [% $all_params %] >[% item.text %]</a>
[% ELSE %]
<a href="[% item.link %]" [% $all_params %]>[% item.text %]</a>
[% END %]
```

**Problem**

The params are not coming in the link only href is printed and link text is printed

**Expected Result**

```
<a href='link 1' // working fine
    param_name1=param_value1 param_name2 param_name2=param_value2 // not working as of now
> link_text //working_fine </a>
```

Comment: what about the other elements in your page, can they be shown right? I have test that there is no problem for me to pass a single url in the hash.

Comment: Everything is workign fine except params, check expected result, have just updated the question

Comment: I've updated it, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I will tried again, you can achieve your goal like this.

```
<a [% FOREACH item IN $all_params %] [% item.key %] = [% item.value %][% END %] href="#"></a>
```

Because in the template, if you directly use the hash, it will recognized it as a hash ref in the template. It can not be parsed directly in your file with the pattern like `key=value`

Comment: Thanks for the answer this works if i have to add it in single place. what I want is assign all parameter to single variable and use that variable in my links